# AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager' -- Login_Manager

Tags: python, flask

I am having issue with Login_manager in my application . The error is thrown here

```
def authenticate(form):
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == form.email.data).first()
        except :# models.DoesNotExist:
            flash("Your email or password does not match !", "error")
        else :
            if check_password_hash(user.password,form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                flash("You've been logged in", "success")
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else :
                flash("Your email or password does not match !", "error")
    return render_template('login.html',form = form)
```

The issue is raise at

login_user(user)

my login_manager is configured below the autheticate as follows.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.secret_key = 'Innalhamdulillah.nahmaduhu.taalanastainubihi.wanastagfiruh!'
    app.run(debug = DEBUG, host=HOST, port= PORT)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_view = 'login'

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(userid):
        try:
            return session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).first()
        except models.DoesNotExist :
            return None
```

and in my declaration

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager,login_user
```

Please how do i addressed this issue and what is the cause ? How do i better understand it ? I was suspecting my `def load_user(userid):` bcos i am not very much clear and this my first. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You run your app before initializing the LoginManager.
So you should have:

```
app.secret_key = 'xxxxyyyyyzzzzz'

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

app.run(debug = DEBUG, host=HOST, port= PORT)
```

Comment: isn't it running the app after initialization?

Comment: I getting this error while using @role_required in my decorator, how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I'm just learning Flask, and I encountered this problem too. I found that I had not initialized the login_manager to the app.

So I changed:

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

to

```
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
```

and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

All flask extensions need to be initilized. Initialize the login manager for use in the app like this:

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
```

and don't forget this:

```
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

If it is not initialized it will raise errors that look like this:

```
Exception: Missing user_loader or request_loader. Refer to http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/#how-it-works for more info.
```

or something like this:

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager'
```

or others.

the line`login_manager.init_app(app)` is the key here.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this has been answered some time ago already, but I came across this thread when I had the same problem, and none of the solutions worked for me.

In my case, my program that I had built yonks ago, started throwing this exception: `Exception: Missing user_loader or request_loader. Refer to http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/#how-it-works for more info.`

After a bit of troubleshooting, I had found that it was python module: `Flask-Login`, I had reloaded my PC and when installing all my software again, the version of `Flask-Login` was now `0.5.0`.

I removed that version of `Flask-Login` and replaced it with the version I had before my reload, with cmd:

```
pip install -Iv Flask-Login==0.4.1
```

And waaalaaa.... it was fixed.

Hope this helps someone like it did me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this also, but it hasn't work with me.
Considering that the official documentation is talking about v0.4.1
BTW, thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader

def load_user(user_id):

```
return User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
```